# Export as PDF with dynamic file name and folder based on cell

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export

I am very new and not progammer based.

I have Excel sheet named "Prin ini" in which like report form. (basic vlookup formula)

Then, I want to export it (not save as) as PDF format. Its name is dynamically based on cell C4 and its folder name dynamically in M4 ( Today() )

I tried to google it, combine some.. but always error..

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim strFilename, strDirname, strPathname, strDefpath As String
    On Error Resume Next ' If directory exist goto next line
    strDirname = Range("M4").Value ' New directory name
    
    strFilename = Range("C4").Value 'New file name
    strDefpath = "C:\Users\febriantot\Desktop\Data Historis Dummy\" 'Default path name
    If IsEmpty(strDirname) Then Exit Sub
    If IsEmpty(strFilename) Then Exit Sub
    
    MkDir strDefpath & strDirname
    strPathname = strDefpath & strDirname & "\" & strFilename 'create total string
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:=strPathname,
End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting? You should remove the `On Error Resume` setting once you've passed the code you want to trap (after `MkDir`) as that may be suppressing an error that would help you resolve this yourself. Or you could write this to test if the folder exists first, meaning you don't need the error trap at all.

Comment: which error do you get and in which line? What is the result in the immediate window if you `Debug.Print strPathname` right before exporting? Note that `Dim strFilename, strDirname, strPathname, strDefpath As String` declares only `strDefpath As String` but all the others `As Variant` in VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable `Dim strFilename As String, strDirname As String, strPathname As String, strDefpath As String`

Comment: Also, your date field is likely to be an issue. Regardless of how the date is formatted in the cell, using the `.Value` would likely return something like `30/09/2021` - which contains `/` - that are not permitted in folder names.

Comment: @CLR sytax error code

  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:=strPathname,

those line turned yellow

Comment: @Pᴇʜ sytax error...

i tried with save as before. it works. it created folder 30-09-2021 then save my document, but in excel

Comment: There is a comma in the end of  `Filename:=strPathname,` remove it and it removes your syntax error.